# Accessing PCI Device from user space programs

Tags: linux, x86, device-driver, pci

I have a device which would be interface with my processor through pcie. I have written driver for it using the existing pci file operations.

Now my problem is how do I access it from user space programs? PCI File operations do not have IOCTL support and hence I cant make an ioctl call unlike other char devices. I cannot use pci_config_read_byte etc. functions as they are meant for kernel space(included in linux/pci.h).

Comment: Why can't you use IOCTLs?  Our PCI/PCIe drivers use IOCTLs all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the [uio](http://lwn.net/Articles/232575/) framework to do this. You can then just export the pci bar to userspace. On x86, you can just treat it as a volatile memory region.